# Load GML layer with Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver, gml, ogc

I'm trying to load a `GML` file into a vector layer and plot it on a map. For some reason the features do not get shown on the map although they get parsed and added to the vector layer.

I tried it with a `GML` file coming from `Geoserver` (making minor modifications to  the source code) and `openlayers 3` seems to have no problem digesting it.

Am I missing something, or is there something with the `GML` parser not supporting custom files?

Code:

```
(function() {} (
        'use strict';

        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.transform([0, 30], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
                zoom: 2
            })
        });

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/echo/xml/", true);
        xmlhttp.onload = function () {
            var format = new ol.format.GML2();

            var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

            // Read and parse all features in XML document
            var features = format.readFeatures(xmlDoc, {
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
            });

            var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                    format: format
                })
            });

            // Add features to the layer's source
            vector.getSource().addFeatures(features);

            map.addLayer(vector);
        };
        xmlhttp.send();
));
```

The original `GML` file is available at [IOC stations GML](http://www.ioc-sealevelmonitoring.org/service.php?server=gml&show=active&showgauges=t). I made a copy of it locally to avoid `CORS`.

Comment: Yes, you have features, but without geometry (check `features[0].getGeometry()` after reading for example). So `readFeatures` doesn't work properly.

Comment: And by the way you should write `featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'` and `dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326'` in that case when your GML is in 4326 ;)

Comment: @SergeyKolosov, you are correct. I found the solution half an hour ago or so. I'll post it.

Comment: @SergeyKolosov, `featureProjection` and `dataProjection` don't seem to be necessary in this case.

Comment: Yep, since you get coordinates from attributes and then transform them manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to be in place, but although that code loads the features, those features still need to have a geometry associated to them. This can be achieved by creating a `ol.geom`, in this case a `ol.geom.Point`.

Code:

```
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        format: format
    })
});

/** This is new **/
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {

    var coordinates = [parseFloat(features[i].get('long')), parseFloat(features[i].get('lat'))];
    // Create the new geometry object
    var geom = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform(coordinates, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));

    features[i].setGeometry(geom);
}
/****/

vector.getSource().addFeatures(features);
```